# Quick way to initialize NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c

Is there a way to do this with NSMutableArray?

```
NSArray *myArray = @[@1, @2, @3];
```

Or, do I have to do:

```
NSMutableArray *myArray = [NSMutableArray array];
[myArray addObject:@1];
[myArray addObject:@2];
[myArray addObject:@3];
```

Or:

```
NSArray *myArray = @[@1, @2, @3];
NSMutableArray *myMutableArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:myArray];
```

Is there a one-liner way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quickest way I can come up with:

```
NSMutableArray *myArray = [@[@1, @2, @3] mutableCopy];
```

Answers also your second question: use the [`mutableCopy`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/nsobject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/mutableCopy) method.

Comment: Yep, it's kind of a waste, but it's about the best one can do.  Another "clever" way to do it is to use NSJSONSerialization with the MutableContainers option, if you're just loading numbers and strings, but that's really ugly compared to the above.

Answer (score 1):

Try `arrayWithArray`:

```
NSMutableArray* myArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:@[@1, @2, @3]];
```